# Gmail Schemas - Not displaying in inbox

Tags: gmail, schema.org, google-schemas

I tried to send email from `x@gmail.com` to `x@gmail.com` following message (from https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/embedding-schemas-in-emails) :

```
Return-Path: <testing.schema@gmail.com>
Received: from ns398878.ovh.net ([2001:41d0:8:54ab::1])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id ei6sm12344329wid.11.1969.12.31.16.00.00
        (version=TLSv1.1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Thu, 29 Aug 2013 06:10:15 -0700 (PDT)
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: None
From: automat <testing.schema@gmail.com>
To: testingschema@gmail.com
Date: Thu, 29 Aug 2013 13:10:15 -0000
Message-ID: <20130829131015.29363.95092@ns398878.ovh.net>


<html>
  <body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context":             "http://schema.org",
      "@type":                "EventReservation",
      "reservationNumber":    "IO12345",
      "underName": "John Smith",
      "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "Event",
        "name":               "Google I/O 2013",
        "startDate":          "2013-05-15T08:30:00-08:00",
        "location":           "Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103"
      }
    }
    </script>
    <p>
      Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p>
      BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
      Reservation number: IO12345<br/>
      Order for: John Smith<br/>
      Event: Google I/O 2013<br/>
      Start time: May 15th 2013 8:00am PST<br/>
      Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think I have done everything correctly, but there is no action button in the inbox.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use Google Apps Script for testing purposes. 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/apps-script-tutorial

I had been trying to send emails to myself with schema.org markup in them using an SMTP client without any success but this worked for me straight out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great tool! Unfortunately, their own example is not working (no visible actions), so I think  there is no point in trying to make my own mail working... :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that Event Reservations work only for Google Now. As [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/overview) says

> Gmail supports 4 types of actions and 1 interactive card:
>
> **RSVP Action** for events
>
> **Review Action** for restaurants, movies, products and services
>
> **One-click Action** for just about anything that can be performed with a single click
>
> **Go-to Action** for more complex interactions
>
> **Flight interactive** cards

As you see nothing is said about event reservations.

Moreover if you just send test email with event reservation example ([from doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/event-reservation)) you'll get no action button as well.

But Google Now has special card for this case (see [doc](http://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/google-now)):

> After an email confirming an event booking:
>
> [image]